# Trying to write a regex that matches a given string and splits it into groups

Tags: regex

I want to write a regex that extracts these details from a given string

Group 1: action (is constant & should be matched “/search”)

Group 2: command

Group 3: query

Group 4: genre (passed with or without “-” if possible)

Condition 1:

```
Matches “/search music heal the world -pop” or “/search movies avengers -action” into four (4) groups.

Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3        | Group 4
--------------------------------------------
/search | music   | heal the world | pop
/search | movies  | avengers       | action
```

Condition 2:

```
Matches “/search music heal the world” or “/search movies avengers” into three (3) groups.

Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3
------------------------------
/search | music   | heal the world
/search | movies  | avengers
```

Condition 3:

```
Matches “/search music” or “/search movies” into two (2) groups.

Group 1 | Group 2
----------------
/search | music  
/search | movies
```

Condition 4:

```
Matches “/search” into a group.

Group 1
--------
/search
```

I am still a newbie when it comes to regex and getting this done has been giving me some trouble. I came up with this `(\/search)\s([^\s]+)\s(.+)\s(.+)` but it only matches `/search music heal the world pop` or `/search movies avengers action` and splits them into four (4) groups but doesn't match the other conditions.

Comment: What *are* the conditions?

Comment: Also, posting pictures with sample data is helpfull, but only to a certain extend. Better would be to post sample data we can copy/paste to work with. =)

Comment: The post has been updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used named and non-capturing groups for clearer result

```
^(?<Action>\/search)(?:\s+(?<Command>\w+)(?:\s+(?<Query>(?:\w|\s)+))?)?(?:\s+-(?<Genre>\w+))?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/HL05pu/2